# Custom JBoss DataSorurce password encryption?

Tags: security, encryption, jboss, datasource, jboss-4.2.x

I'm working with **JBoss 4.2.1GA**.

As you might now there is a way to avoid having [JBoss DataSoruce's password in plain text](http://docs.jboss.org/jbosssecurity/docs/6.0/security_guide/html/Encrypting_Data_Source_Passwords.html). However this technique has a fundamental security flaw which becomes obvious when you look at how [org.jboss.resource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.2/org/jboss/resource/security/SecureIdentityLoginModule.java.html) **decode** and **encode** methods are implemented. The encryption is basically a regular blowfish using a fixed secret key (*"jaas is the way"*).

I'm looking for a way to either change the fixed secret key for one I pick or to change how the encryption/decryption is done.

I'm inclined to think that it can be done by reimplementing **SecureIdentityLoginModule** which is fine, but I'm finding hard to believe there is no out-of-the-box option for this (so far I haven't found any)

Has someone done something like this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848734/encrypting-sensitive-information-in-jboss-configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is how I accomplished this (I'm working on **JBOSS 4.2.1 GA** and Oracle so some stuff may differ between versions and DB vendors):

You need to extend [AbstractPasswordCredentialLoginModule](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.2/org/jboss/resource/security/AbstractPasswordCredentialLoginModule.java.html).

I based mine (Called **PGPLoginModule**) on the out of the box implementation called [SecureIdentityLoginModule](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.2/org/jboss/resource/security/SecureIdentityLoginModule.java.html) the only difference between that and mine is the decode and encode methods which use a different encryption algorithm and process (mine is using a PGP certificate to decrypt a properties file where the password is stored) similar to what is explained in [this article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/06/java-pretty-good-privacy-pgp.html), but you can use whatever method you prefer.

You'll require to add the following jars located on jboss library folders in order to resolve dependencies:

- **[JBOSS_HOME]**/lib/jboss-common.jar
- **[JBOSS_HOME]**/lib/jboss-jmx.jar
- **[JBOSS_HOME]**/server/default/lib/jbosssx.jar
- **[JBOSS_HOME]**/server/default/lib/jboss-jca.jar

You need to JAR your class and place the jar on either:

- **[JBOSS_HOME]**/server/default/lib

or

- **[JBOSS_HOME]**/lib

When you have that you need to configure it on the Security Domain you defined on jboss's login-config.xml so that it uses your class (mine is **org.company.resource.security.PGPLoginModule**) instead of using the default one so it will look something like:

```
<application-policy name="PGPDomain">
        <authentication>
            <login-module code="org.company.resource.security.PGPLoginModule" flag="required">
                <module-option name="username">[DB_USER]</module-option>
                <module-option name="password">[ENCTRYPTED_PASSWORD]</module-option>
                <module-option name="managedConnectionFactoryName">jboss.jca:service=LocalTxCM,name=OracleDS</module-option>
            </login-module>
        </authentication>
    </application-policy>
```

Please notice that depending on the strength and algorithm you decide to use you may need to install the [Java Cryptography Extension Unlimited Strength Policy Files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html) to your JRE.

I hope someone finds it useful.

Comment: I'm trying to extend AbstractPasswordCredentialLoginModule and configure it as suggested by you. But I'm getting the following error: 
`11:58:50,251 ERROR [ExceptionUtil] org.jboss.jms.server.plugin.JDBCJMSUserManagerService@3cf28f60 startService
java.lang.SecurityException: Unauthenticated caller:null`
Any idea if I'm missing something?

Comment: Are you doing this on the same JBoss version I did it?

Comment: I'm doing this on JBoss 5.1.0.GA. I managed to get this working with a few changes. I had to implement some classes like Action which were package local only.

Answer (score 3):

There is an outstanding bug ticket for this issue, at least for JBoss 4.0.x: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-4460

Note the comment:

> The "encrypt the database" password thing is there for passing silly security audits. Ultimately there will be a password of some kind somewhere because the system needs to decrypt the password to send it to the database. It will always be easy for a relatively experienced programmer to hack this. Filesystem/OS security + transport security are your only hope here.

What the commenter is saying is a common issue for all security systems: at some point there is a key which can be decrypted.  Make sure your server's filesystem security is nailed down so that this key is not easily accessed, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following [wiki](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EncryptingDataSourcePasswords) document. It describes two way of encrypting JBoss Passwords. The first one is what you have described and the second one is Password Based Encryption.

Comment: Yeah I saw that one the JBoss Manual. Seams that it just serves for obfuscation, It looks like you end up where you begin, having stuff in plain text somewhere. I did see that coming =D, thanks a lot!